# What feature is this YouTube video using when talking orally with ChatGPT in Chinese?

Tags: chatgpt, chinese

> [image: screenshot from YouTube video showing the user and a screen]

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HZhvfa7fUM), the user talks to ChatGPT (orally) in Chinese about physical and mathematical constants.  This feature looks like it would be extremely helpful for improving my Chinese listening.  I'm not 100% sure it'll be worth forking out the pennies (maybe there's limits or something) so I'd like to see the precise specifications.

**Question**: What feature is this YouTube video using when talking orally with ChatGPT in Chinese?

The video mentions ChatGPT Turbo, which led me to [this](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/8555510-gpt-4-turbo), but I don't think this is what I'm after: I want to have an oral conversation with ChatGPT.

Comment: (For anyone interested, I've managed to do something similar with ErnieBot.  See [my video here](https://youtu.be/3sH4kV6uFyA).  You need a Chinese SIM card and phone number, though.)

Answer (score 1):

ChatGPT Plus can support voice conversations now.  In the app, there is a Headphones icon you can touch which will activate a conversational mode.

[image]

More info here:
https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt-can-now-see-hear-and-speak

Hadn't thought to use this feature for language learning. Brilliant!

Comment: VoiceGPT app does the same. It doesn't work great, though.

Answer (score 0):

> What feature is this YouTube video using when talking orally with ChatGPT in Chinese?

ChatGPT [can](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt-can-now-see-hear-and-speak) do text-to-speech (TTS) or speech-to-text (ASR). I don't know if this YouTube video is using the official OpenAI app.